# Why doesn't typescript let this be assigned to this?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to get a better handle on how `typeof this` can be used in generics.

How come the following produces a type error on `x`:

```
type Equal<L, R> = L extends R ? R extends L ? L : never : never;

class MyClass {

    test() {
        type t = Equal<typeof this, typeof this>;
        const x: t = this;
        // Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'Equal<this, this>'.
        //   Type 'MyClass' is not assignable to type 'Equal<this, this>'.ts(2322)
    }
}
```

While the following is fine:

```
type Equal<L, R> = L extends R ? R extends L ? L : never : never;

class MyClass {

    test() {
        type t = typeof this;
        const x: t = this;
    }
}
```

The `Equal` type ensures a certain type (or results in never).

If I create a var of type `Equal<MyClass, MyClass>` then it is definitely a `MyClass`.

This also works:

```
type Equal<L, R> = L extends R ? R extends L ? L : never : never;

class MyClass {

    test() {
        type t = Equal<MyClass, MyClass>;
        const x: t = this;
    }
}
```

But the same pattern fails with `typeof this`.

I suspect it might related to the polymorphic nature of `typeof this` (the instance might be subtype), but looking at the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) it describes that `typeof this` is ALWAYS supposed to represent the instantiated type.

So I can't see what it's complaining about... `this` will always be `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `Equal<L, L>` being a conditional type means it is not resolved until `L` is a concrete type, rather than a formal type parameter. For example, the following declaration is not simplified to just `type EqualsSelf<T> = T` when you look at the hover tooltip, even though a similar version without the generic parameter does get simplified:

```
type EqualsSelf<T> = T extends T ? T : never
// type EqualsSelf<T> = T extends T ? T : never

type Test = {foo: number} extends {foo: number} ? {foo: number} : never
// type Test = {foo: number}
```

So the issue is that Typescript does not do reasoning like "whatever `L` is, `Equal<L, L>` will always be `L`". Rather, it waits until `L` is realised by some concrete type like `MyClass`, and then resolves `Equal<MyClass, MyClass>` to get `MyClass`.

Since `this` is a polymorphic type, it behaves similarly to a formal type parameter for this purpose, so the conditional type `Equal<typeof this, typeof this>` is not simplified to just `typeof this`. However, it does seem like `typeof this` is "concrete" enough that Typescript can figure it out when the conditional types aren't nested:

```
type Equal<L, R> = [L, R] extends [R, L] ? L : never;

class MyClass {
    test() {
        type t = Equal<typeof this, typeof this>;
        // no type error
        const x: t = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a neat trick! I get the impression that `this` is a bit of a 'special' type with a few caveats...